# Outlook Redemption component - Invalid number of arguments

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am testing the Redemption library for a small project to purge emails from PST files. 
The below simple code with Redemption library to open a PST file should supposedly run fine, but gives an error:

```
RDOSession pstSession = new RDOSession();
RDOPstStore store = pstSession.LogonPstStore(@"d:\1.pst");
```

I get an error  - "No overload for method 'LogonPstStore' takes '1' arguments".

As per the docs [here](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/rdosession.htm), there is only 1 mandatory parameter for LogonPSTStore(). So this error is confusing..

I am using the latest version of the Redemption library with Outlook 2016. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of .Net do not make you specify optional parameters in COM methods. VB/VBA always did that.
You can pass `Missing.Value` for the optional parameters.

Comment: Thanks!! That helped.